# Xamarin build cross platform sdk for native developers

Tags: android, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm going to build a sdk target for android & ios developers.
I thought maybe instead of writing it for objective c and java i will use mono cross platform to my advance.

The only issue is that xamarin can generate apk and ipa.

Is it possible to make it generate static library for xcode developers and jar file and android/java developers ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to create static libraries or jar files with Xamarin for your Obj-C or Android apps to use.  That's not supported.  However, if you have a ton of business logic and others in a static library or jar file, you can create binding libraries and your Xamarin apps can use those.

[Binding To Java Libraries](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_%28.jar%29/)

[Binding To Objective-C Libraries](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/)

Answer (score 0):

No, that isn't possible, yet. Don't know if there will be this kind of feature in the future.